# Aplicação de regressão linear

Tags: python

Possuo duas lista

```
print(lista)
[970084.4148727012, 983104.7719906792, 996164.0, 1006426.5111488493, 1016687.0370821969, 1026941.5758164332, 1037185.9604590479, 1047415.8544247652, 1057626.746645888, 1067813.94679318, 1077972.5805253708, 1088097.584787312, 1098183.7031788095, 1147832.9385862947, 1195602.90322828, 1281768.5077875573]

print(new_list)
[3161, 3185, 3164, 3152, 3154, 3146, 3144, 3174, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Quero aplicar Regressão linear para prever os valores que estão com 0 em `new_list`, para isso selecionei somente os 8 primeiros itens:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = lista[:8]
y = new_list[:8]
```

Separei os dados para treinamento e teste

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=2)
```

E apliquei a regressão linear:

```
regr = LinearRegression() 
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Mas deu um erro:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
>    array=[ 970084.4148727   983104.77199068  996164.         1006426.51114885
>    1016687.0370822  1026941.57581643 1037185.96045905 1047415.85442477].
>    Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single    feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

O que devo Fazer?

Comment: Hey, que tal fazer o [tour] como já sugeri na sua outra pergunta? Você ainda não aprendeu a utilizar todas as ferramentas do site, mas continua postando perguntas. Por favor, faça o [tour] para aprender, ao menos, o básico do funcionamento.

Comment: Desculpe meu desconhecimento, mas não entendi o que tem de errado na minha pergunta, eu já vi o tour e ao meu ver não tem nada de errado, espero que posso ser mais especifico, pois se a algo que estou fazendo errado, consertarei no mesmo momento.

Comment: No momento não há, pois foi editada. Use os acentos graves apenas para formatar códigos em linha. Para trechos de código, basta indentar com 4 espaços em branco. Para facilitar, o editor possui o botão `{}` que indenta o código selecionado.

Comment: Agradeço pelo esclarecimento, e desculpe-me pelo erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `sklearn` supõe que seus dados `X` seja uma lista de listas, porque senão ele não tem como distinguir entre um dataset de, por exemplo, 8 features e 1 exemplo e um dataset de 1 feature e 8 exemplos.

Pra resolver isso, você pode transformar a sua lista em uma lista de listas:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lista = [[elemento] for elemento in lista]
X = lista[:8]
y = new_list[:8]

...
```

Ou usar o `numpy` com `reshape` como sugerido pela mensagem de erro (`Reshape your data using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature`):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = lista[:8]
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 1)
y = new_list[:8]

...
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado.